# Inheriting both abstract class and class implementation in C++

Tags: c++, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I hope this is a simple question.

Can I inherit both an abstract class and it's implementation?  That is, can the following be made to work?

```
class A { 
   virtual void func1() = 0; 
}

class B {
   void func1() { /* implementation here */ }
}

class C : public A, public B {
}
```

I've tried a few variations, and am getting compile errors complaining about unimplemented methods in class C.  I can save a lot of repeated code if I can make this work, however.  Is it possible?

---

I solved this by creating a "composite class" called D which inherits from A & B, but contains the implementation code previously contained in B.  This makes my inheritance model less clean, but it solves the problem without requiring code duplication.  And, as I noted in the comments below, it makes my naming conventions pretty gross.

```
class A { 
   virtual void func1() = 0; 
}

class B {
   // Other stuff
}

class D : public A, public B {
   void func1() { /* implementation here */ }
}

class C : public D {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kirill pointed out: Your premise is wrong.

Class B in your example does not inherit class A (it needs to be declared to do that first).

Thus, B.func1() is something entirely different to A.func1() for the compiler. In class C it is expecting you to provide an implementation of A.func1()

Somebody above posted something along the lines of:

```
class C : public A, public B 
{
      // implement A::func1()
      virtual void func1()
      { 
           // delegate to inherited func1() in class B
           B::func1(); 
      }
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess we've narrowed the problem to one of finding a good naming convention:

class LuaPolygonalGameObject : public GameObject, public Polygon, public LuaItem  // Composite class

yuck!  But it does compile!

Answer (score 2):

`class B` is not an implementation of `class A` in your code. `Class B` should be inherited from `class A` and `func1` should be virtual. Only in that case `class B` will be implementation of `class A`. And then there is no need to inherit from both A and B.

```
class A { 
   virtual void func1() = 0; 
}

class B : public A {
   virtual void func1() { /* implementation is here */ }
}

class C : public B {
}
```

Otherwise you will get unimplemented pure virtual function `func1`.

Answer (score 1):

Make B inherit from A. If that is not possible, using virtual inheritance might also work (I am not entirely sure about this).

Comment: In this case, A and B are very different classes, and really have nothing in common besides a small number of functions.

Comment: When you use non-virtual inheritance, C gets two entirely separate func1 functions.

Comment: it would be pretty hack if B didn't inherit from A and you were trying to get it to override A's function by kinda mashing them together in C

also Diamond inheritance would still require B to inherit from A, it would have to be:
class B: virtual A
class C: virtual A, B

Comment: That "pretty hack" is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse code from B class in C class, try to do something like this:

```
class C : public A, public B {
void func1(){ B::func1(); }
}
```